# Erro ao fazer pedido

Tags: php, api, url

Estou a tentar fazer um pedido numa REST API a usar o PHP Unirest.
O erro que aparece quando faço print é:

> Bad URL, colon is first character

O erro:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Unirest\Exception: Bad URL

O meu codigo:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Unirest\Request as UniRequest;
use CurlFile;

if (isset($_POST['primeiro'])) {
    $where = $_POST["where"];
    $equal = $_POST["equal"];

    $resultado = new pedidos;
    $valores = $resultado->LogIgualA($where, $equal);
}

class pedidos {
    function LogIgualA($where, $equal) {
        $wsURL = "localhost:8080/public";
        $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');

        try {
            $valores = UniRequest::get($wsURL."/visual/json_log/where=".$where."/equal=".$equal, $headers, null);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $valoresAux = $valores->body;

        $valores = [];

        foreach($valoresAux as $z){
            $ID = $z->ID;
            $DateConnection = $z->DateConnection;
            $TimeToServe = $z->TimeToServe;
            $ClientIP = $z->ClientIP;
            $CacheCode = $z->CacheCode;
            $Bytes = $z->Bytes;
            $Method = $z->Method;
            $RequestProtocol = $z->RequestProtocol;
            $RequestIP = $z->RequestIP;
            $RequestPort = $z->RequestPort;
            $RequestFolder = $z->RequestFolder;
            $Auth = $z->Auth;
            $RouteLeft = $z->RouteLeft;
            $RouteRight = $z->RouteRight;
            $ContentType = $z->ContentType;
        }

        return $valores;
    }
}
```

O "isset($_POST['primeiro'])" é quando clico no butao em HTML ele chamar a função dentro do PHP.
Se colocar a variavel `$wsURL com "http://localhost:8080/public"` simplesmente fica a carregar infinitamente.

Comment: **Primeiro:** Acho que o correto é utilizar com o http:// mesmo, só precisamos encontrar o que faz carregar infinitamente. **Segundo:** No foreach vejo que você está salvando os valores em variáveis mas depois não passa ela de volta para o $valores e sempre retorna um valor vazio. **Terceiro:** Não sei o que isso pode causar, mas você está passando o $headers para a função mas não define essa variável antes no código (pelo menos não no código postado aqui)

Comment: já atualizei o meu código, e o que está depois do foreach ainda nao terminei, era so mesmo para testar. Ja andei a procurar o que pode estar a fazer com com o http:// esteja a carregar infinitamente mas também não consigo encontrar nenhuma informação.